# Searching for a user named "Don" with PostgreSQL full text search

Tags: postgresql

We hit a bug with our PostreSQL full text search system where a user whose first name is "Don" was not being included in search results. After some digging, we found that "don" is listed as a stopword in the default full text search dictionary in PostgreSQL (https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/backend/snowball/stopwords/english.stop).

We are using a hosted DB solution so we don't have access to the file system and thus can't create a modified version of the stopword file.

Are there any workarounds for this other than doing a string comparison check? Given that there can be multiple search tokens, it seems pretty bad to have to perform a string comparison of the name fields against every search token.

All the other words in the English stopword file seem pretty reasonable, but I'm really surprised I don't see any other Google/SO results complaining about users named "Don".

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this makes it clear why `don` is a stopword:

```
SELECT to_tsvector('english', 'don''t');

 to_tsvector 
-------------

(1 row)
```

You wouldn't want to remove that stop word.

Full text search is not useful for proper names.

Normally, trigram indexes are better for that.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a late answer.

You can use the `simple` config to generate the search vector for names.

```
SELECT TO_TSVECTOR('simple', 'Don')
```